# Is it possible to add if statments inside php sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have php function with query I want to add different `Order by ASC/DESC` depending on the form value the user selects so I had if statement inside the query line.
I tried but I get no error and no result, but if I without the `if` it works.

```
<?php
    SELECT * FROM Customers
     if(!empty($registro_asc_desc)){
    ORDER BY user_registered DESC, 
    } else  if(!empty($post_asc_desc)){else {
    ORDER BY postDESC,
    }
?>
```

Comment: You can't mix SQL syntax with PHP syntax like this. Do you know how to execute SQL statement in PHP?

Comment: You can use a `case` statement within the `order by` clause if you simply wish to select the column by which the ordering is done.

Comment: your problem is that you cant change a query when in the prepared statement call. Doesnt work that way. define it on forhand, and then prepare it. Ans plit it... so `$query = "blablabla";` if yadiyadi, then `$query .= yadi yadi" `.. with the .= you simply add to the query variable, so there you do your if else statement. When its done, you prepare it and add the variables to it.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius the order depend on the search filter the user chooses, he can choose to order by count or by date or none of them so depending on that value i believe need to have three statments queries well i think

Comment: @Dorvalla I believe what you saying his how DCodeMania mentioned below, tried but no avail, i've posted the way code the way you saying well i think is the way you suggested but did not work maybe i am missing a comma or somthing somewhere I dont know.

Comment: What I mean by `"select the column by which the ordering is done"` is that the case statement can have as many conditions as you need but the actual sort direction (`ASC|DESC`) cannot be set (afaik) with this approach. I've not tested whether the `case` statement could use placeholders ( for use in a prepared statement ) though

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers";

if (!empty($registro_asc_desc)) {
  $sql .= " ORDER BY user_registered DESC";
} else if (!empty($post_asc_desc)) {
  $sql .= " ORDER BY post DESC";
}
```

Comment: it did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the above worked; no error but still no result! Here is my full query, I want to add the if statements on the line of the `ORDER BY`

```
function get_users_by_post_count( $post_type = 'advert' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $users = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT {$wpdb->users}.ID, p.post_count, display_name, user_registered
            FROM {$wpdb->users} 
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT post_author, COUNT(*) AS post_count 
                FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'advert'
                GROUP BY post_author
            ) p ON {$wpdb->users}.id = p.post_author 
            WHERE user_registered between '2021/10/01' and '2022/02/01'
            ORDER BY p.post_count ASC, 
            user_registered LIMIT 5",
            $post_type
        )
    );
    return $users;
}
```

Comment: You can just conditionally concatenate. This is a common practice, and DCodeMania has a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did try but did not work here example with the example mention above

```
 $users = '';
    $users = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT {$wpdb->users}.ID, p.post_count, display_name, user_registered
            FROM {$wpdb->users} 
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT post_author, COUNT(*) AS post_count 
                FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'advert'
                GROUP BY post_author
            ) p ON {$wpdb->users}.id = p.post_author 
            WHERE user_registered between '2020/01/01' and '$data_final_format';

            if (!empty($registro_asc_desc)) {
                $users.= 'ORDER BY user_registered DESC';
            } else if (!empty($post_asc_desc)) {
             $users.= 'ORDER BY p.post_count DESC';
            }
             user_registered LIMIT 20",
            $post_type
        )
    );
```

Comment: the weird thing is that on the url I get the same, if i do without the if statments just a normal order by as the same with the if statments but with the if statments no result